# 階層フォルダを作成するには？

Tags: google-apps-script

「２番目下１」「２番目下２」フォルダを「２番目」フォルダの下に作成しようと、下のコードを書きました。　ところが添付画像の様に「２番目」と同じ階層に作成されます。　何故でしょうか？

```
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("１番目");
var folder1 = folder.addFolder(folder.createFolder("２番目"));
var folder2 = folder1.addFolder(folder.createFolder("２番目下１"));
var folder2 = folder1.addFolder(folder.createFolder("２番目下２"));
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

フォルダ作成自体を行っている部分を取り出してみると...

```
var folder = DriveApp.createFolder("１番目");
folder.createFolder("２番目")
folder.createFolder("２番目下１")
folder.createFolder("２番目下２")
```

すべて`folder`(１番目)以下にフォルダを作っています。同じ階層に作られてしまうのはこれが原因です。

また、`addFolder()`は引数のフォルダを複数のフォルダに所属させるときに使うものなので、今回の場合では不要でしょう。

以下のコードでお望みの動作になると思います。

```
var folder1 = DriveApp.createFolder("１番目");
var folder2 = folder1.createFolder("２番目");
folder2.createFolder("２番目下１"); 
folder2.createFolder("２番目下２");
```

Comment: ご教示いただいたコードで望み通りに作成できました。　有難うございます。　GASの理解の浅さを痛感しました。

Comment: 最近、別の問題が発生しましたので、また質問させてください。　
右側のパネルには"２番目"以下のフォルダが表示されますが、左側パネルには"１番目"のみ作成され、"２番目"以下は作成されません。　フォルダ名左側の三角は右向きから下向きになりますが、何も表示されません。
一体何が問題なのでしょうか？